# compactness of $K$ and $(K,d)$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that if $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $K \subset X$ then $K$ is compact iff it is sequentially compact.

The forward implication has been proved

I am looking at the proof for the backwards implication, so we are assuming that $K$ is sequentially compact. I had a theorem which shows the space $(K,d)$ is compact. Now I have to show that $K$ is compact. The proof goes as follows, let $\{G_a\}_{a \in A}$ be an open cover of $K$ in $X$, then $G_a' = K \cup G_a$ are open in $(K,d)$.

I am confused here, firstly - I don't understand the difference of showing a metric space $(K,d)$ is compact, and a set $K$ is compact. We only defined compactness for a set $K$. Secondly, why does $K\cup G_a$ form an open cover in $(K,d)$

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is part of a somewhat broader result. We'll need some definitions first taken from Munkres' *Topology*:

> A topological space $X$ is **limit point compact** iff every infinite subset $A\subset X$ has a limit point.

Actually, $X$  doesn't need to be metrizable to prove that if $X$ is compact then it is limit point compact (its proof is quite similar to the one seen in a standard real analysis course) but the converse is not necessarily true.

For a proof, suppose $X$ is compact with $A\subset X$ infinite with no limit point. Then for every $x\in X$ there is a open neighborhood $U_x$ such that $U_x\cap A\subset\{x\}$. Notice that $\{U_x\}_{x\in X}$ is an open covering of $X$, but it certainly has no finite subcovering of $A$ and hence no finite subcovering of $X$ which is a contradiction.

Now another definition:

> A topological space $X$ is **sequentially compact** iff every sequence $(x_n)$ of points in $X$ has a convergent subsequence.

and remember that

> If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then its **diameter** $\delta$ is defined as $\delta = \sup\{d(x,y):x,y\in X\}$

Now, this is the result you're looking for:

> If $X$ is a metrizable space, then (1)
>   $X$ is compact iff          (2) $X$ is limit point compact iff         (3)  $X$ is sequentially    compact

We've already seen $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$.

Now suppose $X$ is limit point point compact and consider a sequence $(x_n)$ of points in $X$ with range $A$, i.e. $A=\{x_n\in X : n\in\mathbb N\}$. If $A$ is finite, then there is at least an element $y\in A$ such that there is a constant convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ where $x_{n_k} = y\;\; \forall \;k\in\mathbb N$. If $A$ is infinite, then $A$ has a limit point $x$. Construct the subsequence as follows: Consider $n_1$ large enough such that $x_{n_1}\in B_1(x)$, the ball of radius 1 centered in $x$. Now suppose we've already constructed $x_{n_1},\ldots,x_{n_{k-1}}$. Take $n_k  > n_{k-1}$ such that $$x_{n_k}\in B_{1/n}(x)$ .  Certainly, the subsequence $(x_{n_k})$  converges to $x$ and we're done. Then $(2)\Rightarrow(3)$

Finally, suppose that $X$ is sequentially compact. We'll need to check a couple of things before.

First, we need to show that for any given $\epsilon > 0$ there is a finite subcovering of $\epsilon$-balls.

Assume there is a particular $\epsilon$ such that the previous statement doesn't hold.  We'll construct a sequence as follows: take any $x\in X$ and set $x_1=x$. Notice that $B_\epsilon(x_1)$  doesn't cover all $X$, otherwise we'd cover $X$ with a finite number of $\epsilon$-balls; hence, $X\setminus B_\epsilon(x_1)\neq\varnothing$ .  Suppose we've already constructed $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ and take 
$$x_n\in X\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}B_\epsilon(x_i)$$
Since $X$ can't be covered by a finite number of $\epsilon$-balls, it'd certainly won't be completely covered by $n-1$ $\epsilon$-balls. Then $d(x_n,x_i)\geq\epsilon$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$. Moreover, $d(x_i,x_j)\geq\epsilon$ whenever $i\neq j$, so there can't be a convergent subsequence, contradicting our initial hypothesis.

Now consider an open covering $\mathcal O$ of $X$. We'll now show that there is a $\delta>0$ such that for each $A\subset X$ with diameter less than $\delta$ there is an open $U$ in $\mathcal O$ such that $A\subset U$.

Suppose there is no such $\delta$, then for every $n\in\mathbb N$ there is $C_n\subset X$ such that diam$C_n<\frac1n$ and there is no open $U$ of $\mathcal O$ containing it. Pick $x_n\in C_n$, so by hypothesis, the sequence $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$, and say it converges to $x$. There must be an open $U$ of collection $\mathcal O$ such that $x\in U$ (since $\mathcal O$ is a covering.)  Because $U$ is open, for an $\epsilon$ small enough, $B_\epsilon(x) \subset U$. Take $k$ large enough such that $\frac1{n_k} < \frac\epsilon2$ and $d(x_{n_k}, x)<\frac\epsilon2$, thus $C_{n_k} \subset B_{\epsilon/2}(x_{n_k})$ (since diam$C_{n_k} <\frac\epsilon2$) and we conclude that $C_{n_k} \subset B_\epsilon(x) \subset U$ since for any $y\in C_{n_k}$ we have $d(x,y)\leq d(x, x_{n_k})+d(x_{n_k},y)<\epsilon$. But this contradicts the supposition that $C_{n_k}$  isn't contained by any element of $\mathcal O$.

Hence, given an open covering $\mathcal O$ of $X$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for each $A\subset X$ with diameter less than $\delta$ there is an open $U$ in $\mathcal O$ such that $A\subset U$.  Set $\epsilon = \frac\delta3$ and we know there is a finite subcovering of $\epsilon$-balls. But every of these $\epsilon$-balls has diameter $\frac23\delta < \delta$, hence for every $\epsilon$-ball there is an element $U$ of $\mathcal O$ containing it. Hence we just need to consider a finite number of elements of $\mathcal O$. Thus, $X$ is compact and $(3)\Rightarrow(1)$.